# Convert OwinADAuthentication from .NET Framework to .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-framework-version

How can I convert [this project](https://github.com/trailmax/OwinADAuthentication) into .NET Core?

I tried (according to [this](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/11/18/how-to-target-net-core-2-2/) site) to change the file `ActiveDirectoryAuthentication.csproj` as follows:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

but when I open the file in Visual Studio 2019 it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: That's because it takes a lot more effort to migrate an existing .net project to a .net core project than just changing the TargetFramework. I would say in this case, it is not worth the effort. You should start a new project and just reuse existing code in your new project. Take a look at this page though if you really want to attempt it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-2.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to start fresh. You are following a tutorial that is talking about an existing database/project.

Instead start here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db?tabs=visual-studio which is the same tutorial but actually starts fresh.

At a guess, If you are using Visual Studio, you need to install the .NET Core workloads and/or install the .NET Core 2.2 SDK https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2

Answer (score 1):

As well as updating the target framework you're using, you also need to make sure that all of your dependencies work with `.NET core` too, and in cases where they don't you'll need to find alternative packages that do.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/ offers a wonderful guide on porting to `.NET core`, and also offers a number of CLI tools for checking how easy it will be to port your code.

Hope that helps,

Alex